# recursive algorithm. Is my recursive tracing right?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I wanted to know if I have been tracing this recursive algorithm right:

foo(x,y)
x is an integer and y a non-negative integer

if y == 0 return x

else return (foo(x, y-1))^3

for: x = 1 , y= 1.  I got 1 for this one

x=2 y=3. I got 134,217,728

x=3 y=2. I got 19,683

x = 4 y= 0. I got 4.

and what output does the algorithm return for any x integer and y non negative number?. I am not sure of this question because I don't even know if I did the recursion right.

Edit:

I tried doing the proof by induction but I don't know how to work it out. This is my work so far:

Base case: when y = 0.

(foo(x,0))^3 = x^(3^0) = x^1 = x

What I assume: when y = k (any number). Assume (foo(x,k))^3 returns x^(3^k).

What I need to show: (foo(x,k+1))^3 returns x^(3^k+1).
So, (foo(x,k+1))^3 returns (foo(x,k))^3, by inductive hypothesis I know it will return  x^(3^k). But that does not equal to what I need to show. Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Developing the recursion downwards, we get
$$f(x,y)=f(x,y-1)^3 =f(x,y-2)^{3^2} = f(x,y-3)^{3^3} = \cdots = f(x,0)^{3^y} = x^{3^y}$$
To prove it rigorously, for fixed $x$, prove it by induction on $y$.